# questions on ejb3.0 timer service

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb

I have 4 methods in my Timersession bean,lets say `a()`, `b()`, `c()` and `d()`.

- `a()` should be executed every 6 hour
- `b()` should be execute every 3 hour
- `c()` should be execute every 1 hour

How can I do this by using EJB 3.0 timer service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, you can create multiple timers & can handle it in a single method.

Sample code :

```
//--

    @Schedules ({
        @Schedule(hour="*/1"),
        @Schedule(hour="*/3"),
        @Schedule(hour="*/6")
    })
    public void timeOutHandler(){

        if(currentHr % 1 == 0)  //-- Check for hourly timeout
            a();
        else if(currentHr % 3 == 0) //-- Similarly
            b();
        else if(currentHr % 6 == 0) //-- Similarly
            c();
    }

//--
```

Comment: How does the code obtain currentHr?  For persistent timers (which are the default), catch-ups can be run at arbitrary times, so current system time won't work; Timer.getNextTimeout could be used, but that's messy.  I think using info="" would be best.  (I assumed in my answer that the ejb-3.0 tag meant that EJB 3.1 constructs weren't allowed, but I certainly agree that @Schedule is nicer than interacting with TimerService directly.)

Comment: @bkail - i have provided sample code, not the complete implementation. currentHr is just a variable indicating current hour in 24hr format & timers are based on calendar-based expressions, working with current system time should not be an issue i think.

Comment: That's my point: the system clock only indicates when the timer actually fired rather than when the timer was supposed to fire.  The two can be arbitrarily different, so calculating which method to call based on the current timer is not reliable.

Comment: yes, there might be difference in time, but that would be probably in minutes, & here we are considering hours. I have found timer service reliable enough. I have only tried to figure out the way differently, else what you have suggested is better.

Answer (score 2):

Schedule three separate timers, and use the "info" object to encode which method needs to be called from the @Timeout method.  For example:

```
timerService.createTimer(..., 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000, "a");
...
timerService.createTimer(..., 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000, "b");
...
timerService.createTimer(..., 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000, "c");
...

@Timeout
private void timeout(Timer timer) {
  String info = timer.getInfo();
  if ("a".equals(info)) {
    a();
  } else if ("b".equals(info)) {
    b();
  } else if ("c".equals(info)) {
    c();
  } else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown method: " + info);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why?  It makes sense for independent events to have independent Timers.  You might be able to derive the desired method from Timer.getNextTimeout, but it will be convoluted.