# running my own threadpool in jboss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I'm a newbie to Java EE, EJB3 and JBoss. I'm developing an EJB application which tests for the reachability of several devices using the ICMP protocol every 2 minutes.

The question is, whether it's okay to implement a Threadpool Executor from the `java.util.concurrent` package so that I can create my own pool of threads which can run in the server (JBoss AS 5.1.0) environment or is there a better alternative?

There are several posts out there relating to this topic but I'm simply not able to grasp them probably because I'm new to Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a timer that starts a scheduled tasks when the container starts.
Starting tasks on container startup differs between different Java EE containers.

bkail's answer here shows how to setup a timer: [questions on ejb3.0 timer service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856775/questions-on-ejb3-0-timer-service)

(The accepted answer there shows how to do it in ejb3.1, which might not be an option for ejb 3.0)